# Extract data from Excel file joined by type of data in sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file :

**Excel.xls**

```
Code    date        start   end
2301    12/08/1993  08:02   08:17
4221    12/08/1993  09:04   09:25
2312    12/08/1993  10:02   10:28
1284    19/09/1994  11:02   11:21
2312    19/09/1994  15:57   16:20
1284    23/06/1995  17:12   17:35
2312    22/06/1996  13:14   13:32
4221    22/06/1996  15:53   16:13
4221    05/05/1999  08:06   08:22
2418    05/05/1999  08:10   08:33
2301    05/05/1999  09:12   09:37
2301    05/05/1999  09:28   10:28
2301    05/05/1999  13:28   13:38
```

**Problem :**

The issue is to extract data from excel file to another jointed by`Code` row?

**Desired solution:**

Importing data from excel file to another or a workbook, jointed by number of row `Code` into sheets with the name of data concerned, for example in sheet `2301` I can have only data of person who this code in the excel file :

**Sheet2301**

```
Code    date        start   end
2301    05/05/1999  09:12   09:37
2301    05/05/1999  09:28   10:28
2301    05/05/1999  13:28   13:38
....      ......     ....    ....
```

Im a beginner in VBA so I spent a few days to find a solution so solution.

EDIT :

In fact I have different csv files and I import them to a unique worksheet using this VBA code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCSV()

Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = "path to csv files\"

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
strDestPath = "path to csv files\"

If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    If Cnt = 1 Then
        r = 1
    Else
        r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
        If Cnt > 1 Then
            Line Input #1, strData
        End If
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ",")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cnt = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

and the code works very fine so I have to joined this by data in different current sheets (as I explained before)?

Comment: `spent a few days` If true, may I suggest you hire someone XD

Comment: In those few days, I hope you've found *some* code you can try, or at least an idea. If so, please post that code!

Comment: @findwindow the problem is that im very beginner about VBA Excel, Im sorry about that!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you, yes that's true but what I find is just to import an excel file not opened to a current worksheet, my issue is how to jointed data and named sheet by the name of data such as I explained above?

Comment: Sigh. What you want to do is not difficult XD If you have nothing to show after few days, no amount of guidance is going to help you short of giving you turnkey code.

Comment: @findwindow if it's not good for you "few days" so give us a solution if it's very easy for you?!

Comment: SO isn't a coding service hence my suggestion for you to hire someone. Batman has a heart of gold though.

Comment: What @findwindow means is that, if you've been working on this for a few days, please let us know what you have tried and what has/has not worked.  We're here to *help*, not necessarily *do for* you.  When we can see some effort on your part, it helps narrow down where your problems may lie (in the code).  You held back code that you used, which would have saved time and effort on our part trying to think of what you *could* be doing.  Please read over [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA, you can use a formula.

I assume that each of your sheets ("2301","4221", etc.) is called JUST that.  Also, I'm assuming you have a header row on each one.

In your non-main worksheet, enter this formula (as an array, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag over/down:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$14,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14=INT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))),ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$14)-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!A$2:A2))),"")`

You'll probably need to adjust the ranges, but that should do the trick.  If you have any troubles, let me know!

Now, you can use that formula on any sheet. It'll look in the main sheet (in my example, `Sheet1`, for a match, then return the equivalent info.

Where you will probably want VB help though, is adding this formula to each sheet. Let me know if you need help doing so.

Edit: A note though, this requires that you have saved the workbook somewhere.  The formula part that returns the sheet name doesn't work unless the workbook is saved.

Comment: I don't understand very well Bruce, you can see my edit above please I guess your solution is possible after I import data to unique file and then joined them by data in sheets(data)?

Comment: @Yassou - Oh! That changes things quite a bit.  Next time, please include code in your post.  But the above formulas should work, just have to get them on to each sheet.

Comment: Thank you, but I need some help because I did not get your formula can you change it by reall value following my file above please?

Comment: they are some way to run this formula using vba code?